# Split String[] into 2 String[] arrays with String-manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, string

Suppose I have an array String[] which has 47 characters in each element. The format of the strings is as the following:

```
"My name is Fouad *6,#%$       , 67655-76       " // 30 characters for the name (It may contains special charaters) & ", " & 15 charaters for the phone-number
```

and I want to split each element into two parts: name (with removing the spaces after it not the spaces in between) & number (also with removing the spaces after it not the spaces in between)

so I can have two arrays String[]: name[] & number[]

How can I do such algorithm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String [] array = new String []
        {
                "My name is Fouad *6,#%$       , 67655-76       ",
                "My name is Fouad *7,#%$       , 67655-77       ",
                "My name is Fouad *8,#%$       , 67655-78       ",
                "My name is Fouad *9,#%$       , 67655-79       ",
                "My name is Fouad *0,#%$       , 67655-70       ",
                "My name is Fouad *1,#%$       , 67655-71       "
        };

        String [] names = new String [array.length];
        String [] phones = new String [array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            names [i] = array [i].substring (0, 30).trim ();
            phones [i] = array [i].substring (31).trim ();
        }

        for (String name : names) System.out.println (name);
        for (String phone : phones) System.out.println (phone);
    }
}
```

Comment: but .trim() will remove the spaces in between ? it will be like ""MynameisFouad"

Comment: No it does not. trim() trims the beginning and the end of a string of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

- Create name[] and number[] with the
  same length as your original array
- Loop through the array

  1. fill name[i] with array[i].substring(0, 30).trim()
  2. fill number[i] with array[i].substring(30).trim()

Answer (score 1):

Just use following code

```
"My name is Fouad *6,#%$       , 67655-76       ".substring(0,30).trim()
"My name is Fouad *6,#%$       , 67655-76       ".substring(30).trim()
```